# Make error when trying to build QT app for an "Open Embedded2 device

Tags: qt, compiler-errors, makefile, openembedded

I am getting this error when trying to build my app:

```
make: Wl,-rpath-link,: Command not found
```

My Makefile looks like this, which is a generated file useing qmake program in the OE toolchain.

```
    #############################################################################
# Makefile for building: app_qt
# Generated by qmake (2.01a) (Qt 4.8.1) on: Tue Jun 26 17:49:26 2012
# Project:  app_qt.pro
# Template: app
# Command: /usr/local/oecore-i686/sysroots/i686-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/qmake -o Makefile ap_qt.pro
#############################################################################

####### Compiler, tools and options

CC            = $(OE_QMAKE_CC)
CXX           = $(OE_QMAKE_CXX)
DEFINES       = -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB
CFLAGS        = -pipe -pipe $(OE_QMAKE_CFLAGS) -fpermissive -O2 -Wall -W -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -pipe -pipe $(OE_QMAKE_CFLAGS) $(OE_QMAKE_CXXFLAGS) -O2 -O2 -Wall -W -Wall -W -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT $(DEFINES)
INCPATH       = -I/usr/local/oecore-i686/sysroots/armv7ahf-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/usr/share/qtopia/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I$(OE_QMAKE_INCDIR_QT)/QtCore -I$(OE_QMAKE_INCDIR_QT)/QtGui -I$(OE_QMAKE_INCDIR_QT) -I. -Isrc -Isrc/screens -Isrc/Lists -Isrc/widgets -Isrc/FileIO -Isrc/communication -IQSerialDevice/src -I.
LINK          = $(OE_QMAKE_LINK)
LFLAGS        = $(OE_QMAKE_LDFLAGS) -Wl,-rpath-link,$(OE_QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT)
LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS)  -L$(OE_QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT) -lQtGuiE -lQtCoreE -lpthread 
AR            = $(OE_QMAKE_AR) cqs
RANLIB        = 
QMAKE         = /usr/local/oecore-i686/sysroots/i686-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/qmake
TAR           = tar -cf
COMPRESS      = gzip -9f
COPY          = cp -f
SED           = sed
COPY_FILE     = $(COPY)
COPY_DIR      = $(COPY) -r
STRIP         = $(OE_QMAKE_STRIP)
INSTALL_FILE  = install -m 644 -p
INSTALL_DIR   = $(COPY_DIR)
INSTALL_PROGRAM = install -m 755 -p
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
SYMLINK       = ln -f -s
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = mv -f
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= test -d
MKDIR         = mkdir -p

####### Output directory

OBJECTS_DIR   = ./
```

Does anybody recognize the error and know why it emerges?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: is it 'w1' or '-w1' ? it looks like the variable that references the linker is not defined.

Comment: Can you show us your `.pro` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is generated because the variable `$(OE_QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT)` doesn't exist. So

```
-Wl,-rpath-link,$(OE_QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT)
```

becomes

```
-Wl,-rpath-link,
```

Are you setting the other variables like `$(OE_QMAKE_CC)` and `$(OE_QMAKE_CXX)`, and if so, where? You should add the variable above to this list. It should point to the `lib` subdir of your Qt installation.

This could be for example (here it's Qt version 4.8.0): `/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.0/lib`.

In a local installation in your home directory, it may look like this: `~/qt/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib`.

For Qtopia, you should look in `/usr/local/oecore-i686/sysroots`...

Comment: Exporting the path to $(OE_QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT) the right way, sorted out the problem...
:::export OE_QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT="-L/usr/local/oecore-i686/sysroots/armv7ahf-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib"